# How data is stored in GeoTIFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, multi-band, data-storage

I'm trying to understand how data is stored in the GeoTIFF format. I understand that the file begins with header, where are stored information
which says that the file is GeoTIFF file. I also know that GeoTIFF is only container, so which types of data it can store? When I have multispectral image,
how are the values of the pixels stored? Something like this?

`data_array=[[value1,value2,value3],[value1,value2,value3],[value1,value2,value3]...]`

It would be great to describe it on these pictures or similar pictures. I can't find these informations anywhere. Can you explain it to me?

[image: GeoTIFF structure1][image: GeoTIFF structure2]

Comment: This is all too large question (actually, many questions) to this forum. Tiff specification (121 pages) https://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/com16/tiff-fx/docs/tiff6.pdf, BigTIFF specification http://www.bigtiff.org/, and GeoTIFF standard docs.opengeospatial.org/is/19-008r4/19-008r4.html should help. Overviews are stored into TIFF as additional pages. Come back with focused questions.